# 2 to 1 MUX with 1 single port ram

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to attach two 4Bitcounters to a 2 to 1 mux. I have no idea how to attach two bit counters with a mux. I have to attach the mux to a RAM which I generated using the Quantus Prime's IP catalog.

```
    input i_clk;
    input i_rstn;
    input i_enable; 
    
    output [4:0] o_ramAddress;
    output [3:0] o_bitCounter;
    output [2:0] o_out;
      
    
    assign o_ramAddress = {1'b0,i_bitCounter}; //5bit RAM Address
    
    
    //4BitCounter
    BitCounter bc1(                       
        .clk(i_clk),
        .rstn(i_rstn), 
        .enable(i_enable),
        .out(o_bitCounter)
    );  
    
        //4BitCounter
    BitCounter bc2(                       
        .clk(i_clk),
        .rstn(i_rstn), 
        .enable(i_enable),
        .out(o_bitCounter)
    );  
    
    mux2_1 mux( 
        .in1(),
        .in2(),
        .out(),
        .select()
    
    );
    
    //SinglePortRam  
    SPRAM spram(                                     
    .address(o_ramAddress),  
    .clock(i_clk),
    .q(o_out)
    );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you creating the component in VHDL/Verilog or are you trying to attach them on a .bdf?

Comment: [![4.png](https://i.postimg.cc/QM4D4nFL/4.png)](https://postimg.cc/p9F3yCQk)

Comment: I am trying to attach 2 things to my mux that I have designed. The two things are one is a read address and other is a Write address.

Answer (score 1):

You have two bit counters, 'bc1' and 'bc2'. For some reason they both drive the same output. This violates logical and electrical considerations and makes no sense. They have to drive different signals:

```
    output [3:0] o_bitCounter1, o_bitCounter2;
    ...
    
    BitCounter bc1(    
        ...                   
        .out(o_bitCounter1)
    );  

    BitCounter bc2(    
        ...                   
        .out(o_bitCounter2)
    );
```

Now you have to chose which one of the output is to be used by the rest of the logic using a 2 x 1 mux.

```
    output [3:0] o_bitCounter;

    mux2_1 mux( 
        .in1(o_bitCounter1),
        .in2(o_bitCounter2),
        .out(o_bitCounter),
        .select(yourSelectSignal)
    
    );
```

Of course, the multiplexer have to be designed in such a way that it switches 4-bit wide signals.

Comment: can you look at the picture? https://postimg.cc/p9F3yCQk